# Decimal Separator in legend slider in eCharts

Tags: echarts

Referring to the example chart on https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=map-usa (see also [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RieO5.png)),how can I display the numbers in the slider on the right with a **decimal seperator** (like in the map for e.g. *Texas*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I found it out. My solution:*

replace `visualMap:{}`with this code-snippet:

```js
visualMap: {  
            left: 'right',
            min: 500000,
            max: 38000000,
            inRange: {
                color: ['#313695', '#4575b4', '#74add1', '#abd9e9', '#e0f3f8', '#ffffbf', '#fee090', '#fdae61', '#f46d43', '#d73027', '#a50026']
            },
            text:['High','Low'],           // 文本，默认为数值文本
            calculable: true,
            formatter: function (value) {
                value = Math.round(value);
               let _count=value+"";
                let _st=""
                _count.split("").reverse().forEach((a,b)=>{
                    _st+=a;
                    b%3===2&&b!=_count.length-1?_st+=",":null;
                })
            _st=_st.split("").reverse().join("");
            return _st;
            }   
        },
```

gives you [this solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V8nr.png)